# GetVolumeInformation Error

Tags: c++, c++-cli

So I am getting compile errors, what I am trying to do is use GetVolumeInformation to serialize the drive which will be unique for each person. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Head.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;
using namespace System::Text;
using namespace System::Net;
using namespace System::Net::Sockets;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::IO;
using namespace System::Security::Cryptography;
using namespace System::Security::Principal;

namespace SE
{

    String ^Base::GetSerial(String ^strDriveLetter)
    {
        UInt32 serNum = 0;
        UInt32 maxCompLen = 0;
        StringBuilder ^VolLabel = gcnew StringBuilder(256); // Label
        UInt32 VolFlags = UInt32();
        StringBuilder ^FSName = gcnew StringBuilder(256); // File System Name
        strDriveLetter += ":\\"; // fix up the passed-in drive letter for the API call
        bool Ret = GetVolumeInformation(strDriveLetter, VolLabel, safe_cast<UInt32>(VolLabel->Capacity), serNum, maxCompLen, VolFlags, FSName, safe_cast<UInt32>(FSName->Capacity));
        return Convert::ToString(serNum);
    }
}
```

Then here is my Head.h:

```
#pragma once

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;
using namespace System::ComponentModel;
using namespace System::Data;
using namespace System::Drawing;
using namespace System::Text;
using namespace System::Net;
using namespace System::Net::Sockets;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
using namespace System::IO;
using namespace System::Security::Cryptography;
using namespace System::Security::Principal;

namespace SE
{
    private ref class Base
    {
    private:
        static bool GetVolumeInformation(String ^PathName, StringBuilder ^VolumeNameBuffer, UInt32 VolumeNameSize, UInt32 %VolumeSerialNumber, UInt32 %MaximumComponentLength, UInt32 %FileSystemFlags, StringBuilder ^FileSystemNameBuffer, UInt32 FileSystemNameSize);
    };
}
```

However, when I compile I am getting:

```
error LNK2022: metadata operation failed (80131187) : Inconsistent method declarations in duplicated types (types: SE.Base; methods: GetVolumeInformationA): (0x06000008).
```

Do I have something wrong? Thanks

Comment: The Head.h file causes this, the same class declaration is getting included in multiple translation units and the linker finds a mismatch between them.  Start by removing *private*, that's not valid.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but I think the problem might be because GetVolumeInformation function is a static function, so you need to call it as

```
    Base::GetVolumeInformation
```

inside the function String ^Base::GetSerial. Please try this and see if it works.